# HTML/CSS: how to force text within a tag to be styled with font-style: italic !important;

Tags: html, css

I have [chordpro.php](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/ChordPro) generated html site; the following part is pertaining to this question:

```
<div class="song">
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="songline">
<tr class="songlyricchord"><td></td><td>&nbsp;C </td><td>&nbsp;C7 </td></tr>
<tr class="songlyricline"><td>1. </td><td>Moje malé svetielko, chcem, aby svietilo. (</td>    <td>hey hey hey)</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

The stylesheet is the following:

```
/* chordpro CSS for the PmWiki Chordpro recipe heavily modified by Otto Bolyós
     See http://pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/ChordPro
Copyright 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009 Simon Davis
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, Version 2, as
published by the Free Software Foundation.
http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.
    v0.3 2009-10-01 add songversion, songnewpage, page-break, line spacing
    v0.2 2009-08-20 significant changes to make work properly
    v0.1 2008-05-26 spacing between refrains
    v0.0 2006-12-27 to go with Chordpro recipe version 0.1
*/
body {
    background-color:#fff;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left: 10pt;
    margin-right: 10pt;
}

@font-face {
      font-family: "Linux Libertine Display G";
      src: url("fnts/linlibdg.woff") format('woff');
}

@font-face {
      font-family: "Linux Libertine G";
      src: local('Linux Libertine G'), url("fnts/linlibg_r.woff") format('woff');
      font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
      font-family: "Linux Libertine G";
      src: url("fnts/linlibg_z.woff") format('woff');
      font-weight: 600
}

@font-face {
      font-family: "Linux Libertine G";
      src: url("fnts/linlibg_b.woff") format('woff');
      font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
      font-family: "Linux Libertine G";
      src: url("fnts/linlibg_zi.woff") format('woff');
      font-weight: 600;
      font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
      font-family: "Linux Libertine G";
      src: url("fnts/linlibg_bi.woff") format('woff');
      font-weight: bold;
      font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
      font-family: "Linux Libertine G";
      src: url("fnts/linlibg_r.woff") format('woff');
      font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Ubuntu Mono";
      src: url("fnts/ubuntum_bi.woff") format('woff');
      font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Ubuntu Mono";
      src: url("fnts/ubuntum_b.woff") format('woff');
      font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Ubuntu Mono";
      src: url("fnts/ubuntum_ri.woff") format('woff');
      font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Ubuntu Mono";
      src: url("fnts/ubuntum_r.woff") format('woff');
}

.nav a:hover, .logotext a:hover {

/*  color: #316676;*/

    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px #f3f3f3;
    color: #aaf;
/*  text-shadow: none;*/
    -webkit-transition: 250ms linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: 250ms linear 0s;
    -o-transition: 250ms linear 0s;
    transition: 250ms linear 0s;
    outline: 0 none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#2795B6;

}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#2795B6;

}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* menu */
.menu {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: "Linux Libertine G";
    font-size: 14pt;
}

.logo {
    float:left;
}


.logotext, .logotext a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff; /* keep the color */
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;

}

.nav {
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.nav ul li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.logo ul li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}


.title h1 { /* h1 */
  font-size: 25pt;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Linux Libertine G", serif;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "case", "cpsp", "liga", "locl", "onum", "pnum", "ss01", "ss02", "ss04", "ss05", "dash", "itlc", "lith", "minu", "quot", "sa01", "sa04", "sa06", "sa08", "thou", "frsp", "smcp";
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.espievatko {
    font-family: "Linux Libertine G", serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 70pt;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "case", "cpsp", "liga", "locl", "onum", "pnum", "ss01", "ss02", "ss04", "ss05", "dash", "itlc", "lith", "minu", "quot", "sa01", "sa04", "sa06", "sa08", "thou", "frsp", "smcp";
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:28px;
}

.e {
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "case", "cpsp", "liga", "locl", "onum", "pnum", "ss01", "ss02", "ss04", "ss05", "dash", "itlc", "lith", "minu", "quot", "sa01", "sa04", "sa06", "sa08", "thou", "frsp";
    color: #FF0000;
}

p {
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: "Linux Libertine G", serif;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "case", "cpsp", "liga", "locl", "onum", "pnum", "ss01", "ss02", "ss04", "ss05", "dash", "itlc", "lith", "minu", "quot", "sa01", "sa04", "sa06", "sa08", "thou", "frsp";
}

.basic {
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: "Linux Libertine G", serif;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "case", "cpsp", "liga", "locl", "onum", "pnum", "ss01", "ss02", "ss04", "ss05", "dash", "itlc", "lith", "minu", "quot", "sa01", "sa04", "sa06", "sa08", "thou", "frsp";
}

.small {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-style: italic;  /* this one does not work, donno why */
}

.mono, ::-moz-placeholder, ::-o-placeholder, ::-webkit-placeholder, ::placeholder {
    font-family: "Ubuntu Mono";
    font-size: 11pt;
}


.col2 {
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    -moz-column-count:2;
    column-count:2;
    column-gap:40px;
    -moz-column-gap:60px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-gap:40px; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.break {
    -webkit-page-break-after: column;
    -moz-page-break-after: column;
    -o-page-break-after: column;
    -ms-page-break-after: column;
    page-break-after: column;
}

.texty {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 180px;
    max-height: 400px;
    resize: vertical;
}

.search {
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    width: 97%;
}

.cislo {
    width: 40pt;
}

.white {
    color: #fff !important;
}

.italic {
    font-style: italic !important;
}

td {
/*  padding-right: 2px;*/
/*  cell-padding-right: 4px*/
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

.terminal {
    font-family: "Ubuntu Mono"
/*  background-color: #999999 */
}

.th {
    font-family: "Linux Libertine G", serif;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "case", "cpsp", "liga", "locl", "onum", "pnum", "ss01", "ss02", "ss04", "ss05", "dash", "itlc", "lith", "minu", "quot", "sa01", "sa04", "sa06", "sa08", "thou", "frsp";
    text-align: left;
}

.songtitle { /* h2 */
    font-size: 16pt;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Linux Libertine G", serif;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "case", "cpsp", "liga", "locl", "onum", "pnum", "ss01", "ss02", "ss04", "ss05", "dash", "itlc", "lith", "minu", "quot", "sa01", "sa04", "sa06", "sa08", "thou", "frsp", "smcp";
    text-decoration: underline;
    line-height:90%
}

.songsubtitle { /* h3 */
    font-family: "Ubuntu Mono", serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 10pt;
    line-height:0%;
    text-indent: 50px;
}
.songalbum { /* div */
    font-family: "Linux Libertine G", serif;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "case", "cpsp", "liga", "locl", "onum", "pnum", "ss01", "ss02", "ss04", "ss05", "dash", "itlc", "lith", "minu", "quot", "sa01", "sa04", "sa06", "sa08", "thou", "frsp";
    color: black;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
.song { /* div around entire markup*/
    background-color: White;
    }
.songchorus { /* div, to highlight chorus */
    /* padding-left: 1.5em; */ /* indent chorus */
    font-family: "Linux Libertine G", serif;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "case", "cpsp", "liga", "locl", "onum", "pnum", "ss01", "ss02", "ss04", "ss05", "dash", "itlc", "lith", "minu", "quot", "sa01", "sa04", "sa06", "sa08", "thou", "frsp";
    color: black;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
.songtab { /* div, for tablature */
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: 90%;
    white-space: pre;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
.songline {
    /* table, a chord and a lyrics line  */
    empty-cells: show;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    padding-top: 0.1em;
    padding-bottom: .1em;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
.songlyricchord, /* tr, chord line (above) */
.songlyricline { /* tr, lyric line (below) */
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
.songlyricchord td /* line element containing one chord */ {
    padding-top: 0.1em;
}
.songlyricline td { /* line element containing lyrics for one chord */
    font-family: "Linux Libertine G", serif;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "case", "cpsp", "liga", "locl", "onum", "pnum", "ss01", "ss02", "ss04", "ss05", "dash", "itlc", "lith", "minu", "quot", "sa01", "sa04", "sa06", "sa08", "thou", "frsp";
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    white-space: pre;
    font-size: 16pt;
    line-height: 90%;
}
.songlyricchord td { /* specific chord formatting */
    font-family: "Linux Libertine G", serif;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "case", "cpsp", "liga", "locl", "onum", "pnum", "ss01", "ss02", "ss04", "ss05", "dash", "itlc", "lith", "minu", "quot", "sa01", "sa04", "sa06", "sa08", "thou", "frsp";
    color: black;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
.songlyricline td { /* specific lyrics formatting */
    font-family: "Linux Libertine G", serif;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "case", "cpsp", "liga", "locl", "onum", "pnum", "ss01", "ss02", "ss04", "ss05", "dash", "itlc", "lith", "minu", "quot", "sa01", "sa04", "sa06", "sa08", "thou", "frsp";
    color: black;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
.songcomment { /* div around comments of all types*/
    color: black;
    font-family: "Ubuntu Mono";
    font-style: italic; 
    font-size: 10pt;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
.songcommentsimple, .songcommentitalic, .songcommentbox { /* for span around comments of all types*/
    background-color: white;
}
.songcommentsimple { /* span specific comment formatting */
}
.songcommentitalic { /* span specific comment formatting */
    font-style: italic;
}
.songcommentbox { /* span specific comment formatting */
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 0.2em;
    padding-right: 0.2em;
}
.songdebug { /* span, for debug output */
    font-size: x-small;
    color: Red;
}
.songmessage { /* span, eg unknown directive */
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: smaller;
    color: black;
}
.songversion { /* span, for version display */
    font-size: smaller;
    color: black;
}
.songnewpage { /* div, some browsers may action this formatting */
    page-break-after: always; /* ask browser to start a new page */
    clear: both; /* clear content before page break */
}
/* end of chordpro.css */
```

What I want to do is that in the html example the cell `<td>hey hey hey)</td>` should be italicized.

So far I tried `<td class="italic"></td>`, `<i></i>`, `<div class="italic"><td></td></div>`, `<td style="font-style: italic !important;>`. I had similar problem with the `class="white"`, the `important!` solved the issue then. Now it does not work for `class="italic"`.

**Update:**
[Here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7B2i9-OwPzySG5lRUh6a3dmdzQ&usp=sharing) is a link to html, css and all files in use.

Comment: Your css should work. http://jsbin.com/venubaxe/2/

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem is your font-face declarations.  I can't see the problem, but without the fonts all of the things you tried work fine.

Comment: @jme11: Might be true, because this is the first time ever I use them. I am about to share a gDrive folder and link it in the question, if it could help you to help me out :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want (true) italic, you need to specify an italic typeface. Your `@font-face` rules now refer to normal (regular) typefaces only.

Comment: True, corrected it to \@font-face {font-family: "Linux Libertine G"; src: url("fnts/linlibg_i.woff") format('woff'); font-style: italic;}, but still does not work. I am sure it is an italic variant (check the gDrive in Update #1 of the question post).

Comment: I have just figured out that it did not work becauce I put the class="italic" to the closing tag `</td> not the opening one :). So you all were right ;). The problem was with the italic font-face definition where I defined, by mistake, the regular variant.

But because Jukka answered earlier, I will mark Jukka’s answer as solution, but I have to mention that WellBloud tried to help me to, even by comments. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

Either set some class to `td` like `class="italic"`, then you can use:

```
.songlyricline td.italic {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Or without class, if it's always on the end of the row:

```
.songlyricline td:last-child {
    font-style: italic;
 }
```

Also, make sure that the font you are using has a italic variant. Try using some basic font-family and check if it works. If yes, then find different font to use on your site

**Update 1:**
You have several `@font-face` with same `font-family` name... Just set new name to your italic font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "kurziva";
    src: url("fnts/linlibg_i.woff") format('woff');
    font-style: italic;
}
```

and then apply this new `font-family` to elements you want to have in italic version:

```
.songlyricline td i {
    font-family: kurziva;
}
```

This works on your files. Try that ;)

Comment: It is not always the last-child. The first suggestion, again, sould work, but does not (I work on Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 amd64, now sitting at Win 7 x64, in both os's I use firefox).

Comment: @tukusejssirs yes, the first solution should work, but check that font you are using (Linux Libertine G) if it has italic variant. Or simply insert this code 
.songlyricline td.italic {font-family: arial !important; font-style: italic;} at the end of .css file and see if you have italics where you need to. If yes, then your font Linux Libertine G doesn't have italic variant and you need to look it up

Comment: I am sure LinLibG has italic variant (I have converted the .woff files from .ttf ones using sfnt2woff). I made some typos in the fontface declarations, but still not working (for italic font now I use this css code: \@font-face {font-family: "Linux Libertine G"; src: url("fnts/linlibg_i.woff") format('woff'); font-style: italic;}, but still it does not work. But when open the fnts/linlibg_i.woff font in gnome-font-viewer (in linux), it opens correctly (i.e., no corruption while conversion) and it *says* and visually *is* italic variant.

Comment: @tukusejssirs I've just updated my answer with a working solution. Try it and give info if it works

Comment: Yes, it does work. This is the way I have resolved my problem. Even this works `@font-face {font-family: "Linux Libertine G"; src: url("fnts/linlibg_i.woff") format('woff'); font-style: italic;}`. In the other comment I said it does not, but later on I noticed I have place `class="italic"` in wrong place by mistake (in the closing tag </td>, not the opening one). But thank you for the effort.